# Utilizar dos middleware para una misma ruta

Tags: laravel, middleware

Estoy tratando de utilizar estos dos middleware para acceder a una ruta

Identifica al usuario con el departamento de dirección.

```
class CheckDirectionDepartment
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Verificar si el usuario está autenticado
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // Obtener el usuario autenticado
            $user = Auth::user()->departamentos;

            // Verificar si el usuario pertenece al departamento de dirección
            foreach ($user as $departamento) {
                if ($departamento['nombre'] == 'Dirección') {
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
        }

        // Si el usuario no está autenticado o no pertenece al departamento de dirección, redireccionar a otra página (puedes ajustar la URL según tu necesidad)
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Identifica al usuario con el departamento de Supervisión.

```
class CheckSupervisionDepartment
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Verificar si el usuario está autenticado
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // Obtener el usuario autenticado
            $user = Auth::user()->departamentos;

            dd($user);

            // Verificar si el usuario pertenece al departamento de Supervisión
            foreach ($user as $departamento) {
                if ($departamento['nombre'] == 'Supervisión') {
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
        }

        // Si el usuario no está autenticado o no pertenece al departamento de dirección, redireccionar a otra página (puedes ajustar la URL según tu necesidad)
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

La ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::resource('incidencias', IncidenciaController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'check.direction', 'check.supervision']);
```

En el momento que pongo los dos middleware a la ruta, no me funciona.

Por separados si que funcionan, pero juntos no.

Hasta donde he podido averiguar al ultimo middleware que pongo en la ruta lo bloquea el primero y por eso no me deja acceder, pero no he podido aún dar con la solución a ver si alguien me pueda echar un cable. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: ¿Por qué no hacerlo con uno solo y comparando si el departamento es cualquiera de los autorizados?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ponerlos en el controlador, dentro del método constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['check.direction', 'check.supervision'])->only(['show']);
}
```